# How can I put a variable in the middle of a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to get this to work without adding an additional line? I want to echo "success". Is it possible?

```
<?php
$temp1temp = "on";
$x=1;
if ("temp".$x."temp" == "on")
  echo "success";
?>
```

Comment: It's called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). And the better alternative are usually arrays.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. if (${temp.$x.temp} == "on")

Comment: I forgot the quotes - if (${'temp'.$x.'temp'} == "on")